# Shim class for node's http module using xhr2

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-side

I am looking for a client-side wrapper for the `http` module from `node.js` using `XmlHTTPRequest v2`. This is for using the [clientside](http://projects.jga.me/clientside/) tool to be able to export to client side a `node.js` project. I tried talking to my best friend google, but he is mean to me today.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Have you attempted to use the http-browserify module? It is "The http module from node.js, but for browsers." Sounds like what you are looking for?

Comment: @darelf If i borwserify the 200 lines that i have in the node.js file it turns the code in a 3000 lines of code that even Eclipse warns me at every line for missing commas and brackets. That's why i wanted a shim for `clientside` tool. Any other ideas to have just a small wrapper with the same interface as the http module ?